# How to view .pdf file in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to use Google Doc Embedder by using this code

```
[gview file="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/list.pdf"]
```

but this error keeps on showing up..

> Sorry, we were unable to find the document at the original source. Verify that the document still exists.
>   You can also try to download the original document by clicking here.

I checked in the directory/path to verify and its still there. So what is the reason that this error keeps on showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs doesn't have access to your local machine.  It will need to be on publicly accessible web server for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your file path is wrong. You are pointing to localhost for your server. This is something running on your machine only so google reader would not be able to point to a file on your machine.

You should upload your file to a public server.

Comment: Is this site never going on a public web server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try even

```
 <iframe src="http://localhost:8080/pdf">
```

I think there are plugins for iframe in wordpress ,Try it out..

Answer (score 0):

In my Wordpress I use this plugin for Google Docs to embed .pdf

[DirtySuds - Embed PDF](http://wordpress.org/plugins/dirtysuds-embed-pdf/)

Then in the post use this:

`[embed width="620" height="600"]http://site.com/file.pdf[/embed]`

edit:
You will need live host to upload your .pdf files there.